# Pipe name from variable angular 5

Tags: angular

I have some pipes, I want to do something like:

```
let a = 'myPipe'

<span> {{value | a }} </span>
```

I've been looking for a solution but I haven't found anything, I've tried `eval(a)` and `a.valueOf()`.
The unique idea that I have now it's to do a pipe with an argument that switches to others pipes. Is there other option?